# C printf format for float

Tags: c

I tried the following code

```
int main()
{
    float a = 1.0, b = 25.16;
    printf("%2.1f\n", a);
    printf("%2.1f\n", b);
}
```

I expect the result as:

```
 1.0
25.2
```

instead it shows:

```
1.0
25.2
```

Why doesn't it line up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first number in the format string is the *minimum field width*, which includes all of the characters, including the decimal point. In your case, the field width needs to be at least 4 for the decimal points to line up.

So you want

```
int main( void )
{
    float a = 1.0, b = 25.16;
    printf("%4.1f\n", a);
    printf("%4.1f\n", b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as you suggested. I was wondering why you have to use 4 where in this case values for both a and b are small, 2 digits.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't read your description entirely. I understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
printf("%4.1f\n", a);
```

instead

```
printf("%2.1f\n", a);
```

**syntax**

> %3.2f (print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of 2)

Comment: 3 characters isn't big enough for `25.2`.